# Como modelar de uma forma correta problema de RH?

Tags: banco-de-dados, modelagem, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de tabelas:

[image: DER]

Primeiro: está certo está modelagem?

Segundo: há como melhorar? Reduzir o número de tabelas?

O sistema funcionará da seguinte maneira:

Cada Candidato tem um Objetivo Profissional. E cada Objetivo Profissional pode ser composto por Turno (Manha / Tarde / Integral), Dias(Segunda a Sexta), Profissoes (Analista... etc...), e Pretensao Salararial. Porém ao preencher o Objetivo profissional o Candidato pode selecionar mais de um turno / dia / profissão.

Comment: Uma forma simples de reduzir o número de tabelas é desnormalizar tudo e colocar o sistema inteiro em um megatabelão. Mas isso é uma péssima prática de programação. O que você tem que avaliar não é o número de tabelas, mas sim a qualidade da forma em que as informações estão organizadas.

Comment: Em que sentido você quer melhorar a sua modelagem? Da forma atual sua pergunta está meio vaga demais pro stackoverflow (em modelagem de banco de dados tem sempre mais de uma maneira "certa" de fazer as coisas)

Comment: @hugomg, quando me referir a melhorar, estava me referindo a reduzir o numero de tabelas,e ou outra maneira correta de modelar...

Comment: Pretensão salarial é quase sempre um valor específico e eventualmente uma faixa de valores ("quero ganhar entre mil e dez mil"), mas não uma lista de valores; logo, isto pode ser um campo da tabela Objetivo em vez de ser uma tabela a parte.

Comment: @Caffé, na tabela Pretensão Salarial, tenho faixas de valores definidas tipo `de 1000 até 2000`, gostei da ideia de colocar um campo na tabela objetivo, e para o usuário eu poderia colocar um `range slider` onde ele definiria a faixa desejada...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Até onde dá para entender da descrição, está correto.

Sempre é possível reduzir o número de tabelas. Há poucos dias vi um caso de um sistema inteiro que cabia em uma tabela :D Dá até para ser com uma única coluna e na maioria dos casos em uma linha :) Isto é um *antipattern* chamado [*god table*](http://wiki.c2.com/?GodTable), muito usado em sistemas NoSQL orientados a documento.

É possível reduzir, mas não necessariamente aconselhável.

Se as tabelas de amarras sempre serão acessadas através da `ObjetivoProfissional`, é possível eliminá-las e criar 3 colunas de tamanho variável com a lista de códigos de de cada item. Isso pode ser com um `VARCHAR`, por exemplo, mas isto é detalhe de implementação. Ao contrário do que muita gente imagina, isso pode ser bem vantajoso trazendo pouca ou nenhuma desvantagem, dependendo do que se pretende.

Embora totalmente correta, ela é fora do que as pessoas estão acostumadas e pode dificultar um pouco a aplicação (também pode facilitar, depende). Certamente será mais rápido.

Reforço que não estou dizendo que deve fazer isto, mas é uma opção que eu nunca descarto.

Se precisa do acesso independente aos itens amarrados sem passar pelo `ObjetivoProfissional`, por exemplo, ver todos os profissionais que tem um determinado objetivo, aí é melhor ter as tabelas extras. Mesmo que dê para resolver com a tabela única, será mais complicado. Parece ser o caso, então deixa assim como modelou.